# How to get distinct values for the given date range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
employeeid WorkedDate Hours
   1        1/1/2013  8
   1        1/2/2013  8
   1        1/3/2013  8
   2        1/4/2013  8
   2        1/5/2013  8
   2        1/6/2013  8
   3        1/7/2013  8
   3        1/8/2013  8
   3        1/9/2013  8
```

I need output like below

```
   EmployeeCount    WorkedDate    TotalHours 
        1           1/1/2013           72
        0           1/2/2013           0
        0           1/3/2013           0
        1           1/4/2013           0
        0           1/5/2013           0
        0           1/6/2013           0
         1          1/7/2013           0
         0          1/8/2013           0
         0          1/9/2013           0
```

I don't want to group by Month or Year here. Is it possible to get output like above?

Comment: distinct is a broad term, and why are against grouping

Comment: I need date to join with different tables

Comment: How does your sample data correlate to output?

Comment: I am going to join many tables, which are having date is common field

Comment: We understand your need to join. But how it prevents you from using `GROUP`?

Comment: Closing as "needs clarity" (see various comments).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you really want, but deducing from desired output, IMHO you just need to `GROUP BY` date

```
SELECT COUNT(employeeid) EmployeeCount,
       CAST(WorkedDate AS DATE) WorkedDate,
       SUM(Hours) Hours
  FROM Table1
 WHERE WorkedDate BETWEEN '2013-01-02' AND '2013-01-03'
 GROUP BY CAST(WorkedDate AS DATE)
```

Assuming that you have sample data like this

```
| EMPLOYEEID | WORKEDDATE | HOURS |
-----------------------------------
|          1 | 2013-01-01 |     8 |
|          1 | 2013-01-02 |     8 |
|          1 | 2013-01-03 |     8 |
|          2 | 2013-01-01 |     8 |
|          2 | 2013-01-02 |     8 |
|          2 | 2013-01-03 |     8 |
|          3 | 2013-01-01 |     8 |
|          3 | 2013-01-02 |     8 |
|          3 | 2013-01-03 |     8 |
```

This query will give you following output

```
| EMPLOYEECOUNT | WORKEDDATE | HOURS |
--------------------------------------
|             3 | 2013-01-02 |    24 |
|             3 | 2013-01-03 |    24 |
```

Here is a **[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5644/9)**

Comment: @Somashekhar Did it help? Is it what you wanted?

Comment: No, I want in different way. however you have taken wrong data. my table data is different

Comment: @Somashekhar Well, if you need more help, then please explain what are the rules to get the desired output from sample data you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. However you may need to generalize this. I could not as requirement is not clear.

```
;with cte1 as
(select min(workeddate) MIN_date from test group by employeeid),

cte2 as 
(select min_date  min_date from cte1
 except
 select min(min_date)from cte1)


select * from 
(select 1 EID,min(min_date) WORKDATE ,(select sum(hours) from test)Hours from cte1

union 

select 1,min_date , 0 from cte2
union
select 0,workeddate,0 from test where workeddate not in
    (select min_date from cte1))a
order by workdate
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1032/23)